# How to detect if an OpenVPN connection has disconnected?

Tags: networking, bash, internet, vpn, openvpn

I have a machine that is connected to a VPN through OpenVPN. Is there a way to detect if the connection has dropped and run a script in the event of the disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

Just ping a host *inside your network* that is normally always available and if the ping returns anything except 0, run the script...

```
while :
do
  ping -c 1 -n -W 2 HostName
  iPingReturn=$?
  if [[ $iPingReturn != 0 ]] ; then
    ScriptToRunInCaseOfFailure.sh
  fi
done
```

The disadvantage of this system is that if *that specific host* goes down, your script thinks the network is down, therefore I normally do a send-notify, not run a script...

Comment: Would it make sense to just ping my network's router then?

Comment: Definitely not *your* router.  ;-)  The router on the other end is a great idea!  :)  I'm modifying my script!  (I used to ping 2 hosts just to be sure, but then it was a quick-and-dirty solution that I needed *right now*)

Comment: @beatsforthemind: As you're a reputation 13 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby but if not? :)   Let's imagine that he wanna run this on server, then he can check if host is still connected via openvpn management interface. Then no ping-pong games needed :)